# Density of inner product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ be a random vector, such that $X_j\ne X_k,j\ne k$ and all components are non-degenerate and $a$ deterministic vector with non-zero coordinates. If $X_1$ is continuous random variable, does it follow that $a'X$ is continuous random variable?

What is nesessary and sufficient condition for $a'X$ be continuous random variable?

Comment: Who is $X_1$? Maybe you mean "$X$ is continuous random variable...", right?

Comment: Perhaps $X_1$ is the first component of $X$???

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by editing it to remove the content.

Answer (score 2):

> If $X_1$ is continuous random variable, does it follow that $a′X$ is continuous random variable?

No; say $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are all independent, $X_1$ is continuous, $a=(0,1,\dots,1)$ and $X_2,\dots,X_k$ are all degenerate with the value $0$. Then $a'X$ is degenerate with the value $0$, and hence is not continuous.

> What is nesessary and sufficient condition for $a′X$ be continuous random variable?

IDK; there seem to be a lot of different cases, most of which are unrelated. For example, if $X$ is a continuous random vector then $a'X$ is a continuous random variable. But also, if $a$ has first component equal to $0$ and $X_2,\dots,X_k$ are all continuous, then $a'X$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm not interested in such cases, $a$ has only non-zero components.

Comment: @user298615 If (for $k=2$) $X_2=X_1$ and $a_1=-a_2$, then $a'X=0$ regardless of distribution of $X_1$. If you assume independence then the answer is positive. As well as in many other cases.

Comment: Than you. I'm also not interested in this case.

Comment: Well, if (for $k=3$) $X_3=X_1+X_2$ and $a_1=a_2=-a_3$, then $a'X=0$... though you're probably not interested in this case as well. Could you perhaps give some more context about this problem -- where did it come up / what made you think of it? That way it might be easier to figure out what cases you _are_ interested in.